# Need help to debug mutex dead lock

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, mutex, deadlock

I have a mutex dead lock in the following code:

```
CRegistry::CRegistry()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&_Mutex, NULL);
}

CRegistry::~CRegistry()
{
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&_Mutex);
}

MR_RESULT CRegistry::Register(const REGISTRY_KEY &Id, const REGISTRY_ITEM &Item)
{
    pair<REGISTRY::iterator, bool> Result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&_Mutex);
    Result = _Registry.insert(pair<REGISTRY_KEY, REGISTRY_ITEM>(Id, Item));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_Mutex);

    if (Result.second == true)
        return MR_RESULT_OK;
    else
        return MR_RESULT_ERROR;
}

MR_RESULT CRegistry::UnRegister(const REGISTRY_KEY &Id)
{
    REGISTRY::size_type Result;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&_Mutex);
    Result = _Registry.erase(Id);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&_Mutex);

    if (Result == 1)
        return MR_RESULT_OK;
    else
        return MR_RESULT_ERROR;
}
```

The `_Mutext` is a class member and is not used in any other places in the code. At some point I can see a thread stuck trying to lock the already locked mutex.

There are both real-time and non-real-time threads locking the mutex. I understand there can be be priority inversion but how can this cause dead lock?

Comment: Can you post the code to `pthread_mutex_lock(&_Mutex);` ? I could see a deadlock happening if that code doesn't handle a lock being already in place correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that _Registry.insert() or _Registry.erase() is throwing an exception?  That would leave the mutex locked...

Comment: Why do all people like *reserved identifiers* so much? You are not allowed to use identifiers starting with underscore and an upper case letter. `_Registry` and `_Mutex` are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Is `CRegistry` copyable? Default copy constructor and assignment operator? Is it copied anywhere?

Comment: Are **both** `_Registry` and `_Mutex` class-level? I.e. both have `static` keyword in front of them?

Comment: What type is the `_Registry` object?  Is it possible that the `insert()` or `erase()` functions also acquire `_Mutex`? By default, a pthread mutex has type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` which cannot be acquired recursively. From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutexattr_settype.html - "attempting to recursively lock a mutex of this type results in undefined behaviour"

Comment: @Nemo I don't catch exceptions in this part of code so anything thrown would terminate the application.

Comment: @hmj CRegistry always has one instance only.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic _Registry is a member of a unique application-level object and _Mutex is a member of _Registry. _Registry is std::map

Comment: Is there _another_ mutex (beside `_Mutex`) being used by concurrent threads? Also, what is your call stack at the moment of the deadlock - this should tell you on which mutexes (or other synchronization objects such as semaphores) the threads are waiting?

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic There are other mutexes used in other thread but when I stop in dead lock the debugger shows me only one locking operation in the stack - the one that is stuck on this mutex. As if I could exit Register() without unlocking the mutext and then entered it again.

Comment: So, there is _only one_ blocked thread and the remaining threads are able to proceed, correct? If so, this might be an indication of a memory corruption somewhere else in the program. Other than that, are you forcibly aborting the threads? If you do, then there is a chance the thread will be killed after `pthread_mutex_lock` but _before_ `pthread_mutex_unlock`.

Comment: @Branko Dimitrijevic Correct. Memory corruption was my first guess but the mutex structure looks fine. All the threads are created when application starts, none aborted.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems perfectly fine to me. Are you sure _Mutex is not used anywhere else?

Valgrind toolset includes [Helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html), a pthread debugger that could help you bust deadlocks. Maybe you could run it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a deadlock or just a thread blocked for a long time by other higher priority threads?

Have you looked into using

```
pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol (&attr, PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT)
```

to avoid the priority inversion problem?